# Modelsim, Fatal: (vsim-3828) Could not link 'vsim_auto_compile.so on Manjaro Linux

Tags: gcc, modelsim, manjaro

I'm trying to compile a uvm project on my machine and I keep getting the following error message. I'm on Manajaro, I have multilib enabled on my system and I have followed the instructions on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Altera_Design_Software#Manual_installation) All the required dependencies are Installed.

I can start modelsim from commandline without any issues, but when I call this makefile, it always fails at the below line. Which makes me believe I might be missing something related to gcc, but I'm not sure what that is and googling this particular issue has yielded no results.

```
Compiling /tmp/cyberbemon@cyberbemon-x570aorusmaster_dpi_77438/linux_gcc-5.3.0/exportwrapper.c
# ** Fatal: ** Fatal: (vsim-3828) Could not link 'vsim_auto_compile.so': cmd = '/opt/modeltech/gcc-5.3.0-linux/bin/g++ -shared -fPIC -m32 -o "/tmp/cyberbemon@cyberbemon-x570aorusmaster_dpi_77438/linux_gcc-5.3.0/vsim_auto_compile.so" /home/cyberbemon/Development/uvm/final/tb_build/sub_system_tbs/pss_tb/sim/work/_dpi/auto_compile@/linux_gcc-5.3.0/*.o  "/tmp/cyberbemon@cyberbemon-x570aorusmaster_dpi_77438/linux_gcc-5.3.0/exportwrapper.o"   -Wl,-Bsymbolic '
# (vsim-50) A call to system(/opt/modeltech/gcc-5.3.0-linux/bin/g++ -shared -fPIC -m32 -o "/tmp/cyberbemon@cyberbemon-x570aorusmaster_dpi_77438/linux_gcc-5.3.0/vsim_auto_compile.so" /home/cyberbemon/Development/uvm/final/tb_build/sub_system_tbs/pss_tb/sim/work/_dpi/auto_compile@/linux_gcc-5.3.0/*.o  "/tmp/cyberbemon@cyberbemon-x570aorusmaster_dpi_77438/linux_gcc-5.3.0/exportwrapper.o"   -Wl,-Bsymbolic  >'/tmp/questatmp.AFzKOV' 2>&1) returned error code '1'.
# The logfile contains the following messages:
# /lib/crti.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues was caused by Modelsim using a different gcc version, manually deleting all the gcc-*.*.*-linux folders from modelsim directory forced it to use my system GCC and that has solved the issue.

This solution was suggested [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Programmable-Devices/Intel-HLS-Compiler-Could-not-link-vsim-auto-compile-so/td-p/246135)

Instead of manually deleting it, you can re-run the installer and choose to remove the GCC components. You will get the same result.